# A question involving Lindeberg-Levy CLT

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, weak-convergence, stochastic-analysis, central-limit-theorem

Suppose $X_k$ are i.i.d. random variables with $E(X_1)=0$ and $0< E(X_1^2)<\infty$. Define $$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^nX_k$$ I want to show that $\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}S_n=-\infty$ and  $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}S_n=\infty$ almost surely.
Now I know I am supposed to use Lindeberg-Levy CLT, which states that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n X_i\xrightarrow{D}N(0,E(X_1^2))$$ in this specific case. However, I am having trouble using the convergence in distribution to show that $$P(\omega\in\Omega:\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}S_n=-\infty)=1$$ A hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: the events $A = \{ \liminf_{n \to \infty} S_n = -\infty \}$ and $B = \{ \limsup_{n \to \infty} S_n =\infty\}$ are tail events, so Kolmogorov's $0-1$ law tells us that $P(A), P(B) \in \{ 0,1 \}$. Now use the CLT to show that in fact $P(A), P(B) > 0$ and conclude.

Comment: If I assume, $\limsup_{n\to \infty}{S_n}\xrightarrow{a.s.}C\in[-\infty,\infty)$ If $C=-\infty$, $E(\lim_{n\to\infty}{S_n})\neq 0$,  if $\limsup_{n\to \infty}{S_n}\xrightarrow{a.s.}C\in(-\infty,\infty)$ then $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\rightarrow0$, wich either means $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\xrightarrow{D}0$ or $E(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}})\neq0$. All of wich would contradict $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\xrightarrow{D}N(0,E(X_1^2)).$ same argument would work for liminf. Therefore the probabilities must be positive. Is my argumentation correct?

Comment: @MathR Yes, your argument is correct.